# What happens if you run out of password attempts?

Tags: passwords, authentication, android

In Samsung Knox, you have 20 password attempts. However, it is never explained what happens if you run out of attempts. Does it delete your Knox data, do you need to enter the recovery PIN or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help: https://support.samsungknox.com/entries/28604817-What-happens-if-I-enter-my-password-incorrectly-

It seems to indicate data stored in the Knox container will be deleted.

Comment: "How to delete someone's data in 20 simple steps."